# When I change my language direction to RTL there's a large whitespace on the left

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

When I change my language direction from left-to-right to right-to-left, there's a large whitespace on the left of the web page in wordpress. I inspected it, but I'm unable to find out why the whitespace is there.

[image]

Comment: Is there usually a large white space on the right when the language is LTR?

Comment: No code, no way to know where is the problem

Comment: How does it look in LTR?

Comment: I _imagine_ that the "main content element" adds padding (or margin) on the left to make room for the side-bar, and that changing the text direction has caused the side-bar to swap sides, but not this padding. _But_ without a working example, I cannot say for sure.